# How to merge this two def index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've 2 different `index` actions, can anyone help me to merge this?

First def index (for tags):

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Second  def index (for categories):

```
def index
  if params[:category].blank?
    @posts = Post.all
  else
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do

```
def index
  if params[:tag].present?
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  elsif params[:category].present?
    @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
    @posts = @category.posts       
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ransack for my filtering and sorting: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Its pretty easy to set up and will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short version:

```
def index
  @posts =
    if params.key?(:tag)
      Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params.key?(:category)
      Post.joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: params[:category] })
    else
      Post.all
    end
end
```

However, I wonder if this situation actually warrants 3 different routes and controllers:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories, only: [] { resources :posts, only: :index }
resources :tags, only: [] { resources :posts, only: :index }
resources :posts, only: :index
```

then

```
# categories_posts_controller.rb
class CategoriesPostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:category_id] })
  end
end
```

and so forth:

```
# tags_posts_controller.rb
class TagsPostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag_id])
  end
end
```

If you don't have an `id` you can use, you can change the param name in the route to be whatever you want.

```
resources :categories, only: [] { resources :posts, only: :index, param: :name }
```